# Where is dnsmasq.conf in Android phone?

Tags: android, android-intent, dnsmasq

In the command line of Android, there are dnsmasq commands. But where are all the config files (dnsmasq.conf, dnsmasq.pid...)?

As far as I try is creating my own configuration files and using the following command:

```
dnsmasq --conf-file=the/location/of/my/file
```

It says:

> dnsmasq: failed to open pidfile /var/run/dnsmasq.pid: No such file or directory

When I create pid file it says:

> dnsmasq: failed to open pidfile dnsmasq.pid: Read-only file system

Any recommendations on how I can control my dnsmasq (DHCP, DNS server)?

Answer (score 4):

Debug mode (`-d` or `--no-daemon`) avoids the need for the pid file by not forking, if that helps.

Update: `--pid-file` with no arguments looks like a nicer way of avoiding the need for a pid file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should probably run it as root to overcome the latter problem.  As for the former problem, I have no idea yet.  A workaround might be to start dnsmasq with a script, passing config via command line.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store its process-id, `dnsmasq` requires a pid file. It therefore requires the right permissions to write it.

You should just create a file called `dnsmasq.pid`, somewhere on your system, and give it to dnsmasq using `dnsmasq --pid-file <path/to/your/dnsmasq.pid>`. Be sure that `dnsmasq` has the rights to access this file.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally on `/system/etc` or just `/etc` and
Try to run `dnsmasq` via `-d` or `--no-daemon` control to avoid the pid file error.